# How to call flow from another, separate flow?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I have 2 different flows, one is responsible for registration and another for making an order, the order flow asks user's login and finds login in database if user doesn't exist it offers to register, i want make redirect from flow with order to flow with registration and then come back to order flow, but i cant use subflow couse register flow must be independent. I tried to make redirection by this code, 
`<view-state id="register" view="redirect:/registrarting-flow" model="user" >`
but SWF doesn't consider `redirect:/registrarting-flow` as redirection it tries to find .jsp file using this text. How to make redirection from one flow to another ? Is it possible at all ? Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use a redirect it needs to be in an end-flow, something like that:

```
<end-state id="register" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:/registrarting-flow"/>
```

Also, your problem might be a more general "login" pb. Your security layer should be configured to automatically send a non logged-in user to the login page, and come back to the original page after login succeeds. You might want to look into using Spring Security